# make regex find smallest groups in bbcode

Tags: javascript, regex, bbcode

I am working in Javascript and I have the following regex:

```
[img]([a-z0-9\-\./]+[^"\' ]*)[/img]/g
```

When I have the following text (with space separating between the 2 groups):

```
[img]http://www.bla.com[/img] [img]http://www.bla.com[/img]
```

the regex finds the 2 separate groups successfuly.

However when given the following text (without space separating between the 2 groups):

```
[img]http://www.bla.com[/img][img]http://www.bla.com[/img]
```

the regex does not separate it into 2 groups, but rather 1 big group with `http://www.bla.com[/img][img]http://www.bla.com` inside it.

What am I missing in order to make the regex find the smallest groups when they are not separated by a space?

Comment: Or shorter: `\[img]([a-z0-9.\/:]+)\[\/img]`   https://regex101.com/r/FgsVju/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
/\[img]([-a-z0-9.\/]+[^"'\s]*?)\[\/img]/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/n7X2RP/1)

- `[` and `/` etc need to be escaped in regex to avoid it being interpreted as character class.
- Using `*?` we use lazy quantifier to match as little as possible before matching `[/img]`
- If we are placing `-` at the start or end in a character class then it doesn't need escaping
- dot doesn't need to be escaped in a character class

Answer (score 1):

why not just write it like this:

```
\[img](.*?)\[\/img]/g
```

notice: use `?` to forbid greedy matching.